# UTF8 Beginning of File characters are breaking serializer & readers

Tags: c#, unicode, utf-8, xml-serialization

Okay, I'm trying to work with UTF8 text files. I'm constantly fighting the BOM chars that the writer drops in for UTF8, which blows up pretty much anything I need to use to read the file including serializers and other text readers.

I'm getting a leading six bytes of data:

```
0xEF
0xBB
0xBF
0xEF
0xBB
0xBF
```

(now that I'm looking at it, I realize there's two characters there.  Is that the UTF8 BOM marker? Am I double encoding it)?

Notice the serializer encodes to UTF8, then the memory stream gets a string as UTF8, then I write the string to the file with UTF8... seems like a lot of redundancy.  Thoughts?

```
//I'm storing this xml result to a database field. (this one includes the BOF chars)
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    Utility.SerializeXml(ms, root);
    xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());

}


//later on, I would take that xml and then write it out to a file like this: 
File.WriteAllText(path, xml, Encoding.UTF8);



public static void SerializeXml(Stream output, object data)
{
    XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(data.GetType());
    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    settings.Indent = true;
    settings.IndentChars = "\t";
    settings.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    XmlWriter writer = XmlTextWriter.Create(output, settings);
    xs.Serialize(writer, data);
    writer.Flush();
    writer.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yeah, that's two BOMs. You're encoding to UTF-8 twice and each time adds a pseudo-BOM, due to the extremely unfortunate fact that:

```
Encoding.UTF8
```

means “UTF-8 with a pointless, meaningless U+FEFF stuck to the front to screw up your applications”. Try instead using

```
new UTF8Encoding(false)
```

which should [give you a less sucky version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s064f8w2.aspx).

Comment: Perfect! This answered my question. I was able to write the files without the BOM. I replaced all the locations using `Encoding.UTF8` with new `UTF8Encoding(false)`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is a BOM.

Yes some older JDK's had a bug that blew up on UTF-8 BOM data. And two of them will confuse even a modern version of Java.

The solution I used was to stick a pushback stream on the front and filter it out.

Or use a more modern version of Java.

Answer (score 1):

The byte sequence 0xEF 0xBB 0xBF is the UTF-8 encoding of U+FEFF, which is the Unicode BOM (byte order mark).  It is unnecessary in [UTF-8](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html), but crucial in UTF-16 or UTF-32.

You've got the same sequence twice.

The only good thing to do with them is ignore and/or delete them.